# Body errors not triggering express-validator

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

The validation middleware code is not triggered in the code I created, although all the logging flags are executed.

```
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");

module.exports = {
    validateUsers(req, res, next) {
        if (req.method === "POST") {
            console.log(req.body.email);
            check(["email", "Must consist only of letters."]).isEmail();
        }

        const errors = validationResult(req);

        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.json(errors);
        }  else {
            return next();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried sending `req` and `req.body` with `check`, as well as using `body` with both options. Console logs show a non-email string supplied, and I've tried other fields and other (failing) values.

Can anyone point me in a helpful direction? I've used older versions with `checkBody`, but I'm stuck with these. I've been fussing with `app.js`, but it's got no uncommented code right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`check` returns a middleware, but you are not using this and passing the required args to it.

```
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");

module.exports = {
    validateUsers(req, res, next) {
        if (req.method === "POST") {
            console.log(req.body.email);
            const middleware = check(["email", "Must consist only of letters."]).isEmail();
            middleware(req, res, next)
           
        }

        const errors = validationResult(req);

        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.json(errors);
        }  else {
            return next();
        }
    }
}
```

I'd suggest though this is a little unergonomic. It might not even work, because that middleware returned from `check` could call next, and then your code wouldn't make sense. It's designed to be used differently. It'd probably be cleaner to do like:

```
const { body, validationResult } = require("express-validator");

module.exports = {
    validateUsers: [
            body(["email", "Must consist only of letters."]).isEmail(),
            (req, res, next) => {
                const errors = validationResult(req);

                if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
                    return res.json(errors);
                }  else {
                    return next();
                }
            }
        ]
}
```

And then use like:

```
app.post('/thing', validateUsers, (req, res, next) => {
   // you'd get here only if there were no issues
})
```

Comment: Yes; I had to remove my brackets in my call to the method, but that's my mistake and not something you could know without recreating.

Full disclosure: I learned Node/Express a few years ago, and I'm using old commits to guide me as I pick it back up after a long time with just Java/Spring Boot. It's adding conceptual help, but has pitfalls - obviously. Thanks for your time.